# Wrong record being deleted NodeJS + React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building a fullstack React + NodeJS to-do list app following a tutorial. I've created a React Task component that displays info for a particular task and provides update/delete buttons. For some reason, my React updateTask and deleteTask functions update/delete the oldest task regardless of which task I've selected to change.

I'm using the *update* state variable in React to toggle the update form.
Also, logging *res* in the *updateTask* function returns success and the correct id to update. However, this is not the id that actually gets updated.

React Task component (Task.js):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Task extends Component {

    constructor({_id, title, due, desc}) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            id: _id,
            title: title,
            due: due,
            desc: desc,
            update: false
        }
        this.updateTask = this.updateTask.bind(this);
        this.deleteTask = this.deleteTask.bind(this);
    }

    updateTask = () => {
        const {id, title, due, desc} = this.state;
        axios.post("/tasks/update", {
            id: id,
            update: {
                title: title,
                due: due,
                desc: desc
            }
        })
        .then(
            res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            }
        );
    };

    deleteTask = () => {
        const {id} = this.state;
        axios.delete("/tasks/delete", {
             id: id
        });
    };

    render() {
        const {id, title, due, desc, update} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="task">
                <div>{id}</div>
                {update ? 
                <div className="task-update">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
                        value={title}
                    />
                    <input
                        type="date"
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ due: e.target.value })}
                        value={!due ? "" : due.slice(0,10)}
                    />
                    <textarea
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ desc: e.target.value })}
                        value={!desc ? "" : desc}
                    />
                    <button onClick={this.updateTask}>
                        Update Task
                    </button>
                </div> 
                : 
                <div className="task-show">
                    <div className="task-info">
                        <div>{title}</div>
                        <div>{!due ? "no date" : due.slice(0,10)}</div>
                        <p>{desc}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="task-btns">
                        <button 
                            className="task-edit"
                            onClick={e => this.setState({update: true})}
                        >
                        </button>
                        <button 
                            className="task-done"
                            onClick={() => this.doneTask()}
                        ></button>
                        <button 
                            className="task-del"
                            onClick={this.deleteTask}
                        >
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Task;
```

NodeJS task controller:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const Task = require("../models/task");
const Data = require("../models/data");

router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  Task.find((err, tasks) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, tasks: tasks });
  });
});

router.post("/update", (req, res) => {
  const { id, update } = req.body;
  Task.findOneAndUpdate(id, update, err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, id: id});
  });
});

router.delete("/delete", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  Task.findOneAndDelete(id, err => {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

router.post("/create", (req, res) => {
  let task = new Task();

  const {title, due, desc} = req.body;

  if (!title) {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      error: "INVALID INPUTS"
    });
  }

  task.title = title;
  task.due = due;
  task.desc = desc;

  task.save(err => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by wrong record. Which record is being updated/deleted instead?

Comment: @PrakashSharma Hi Prakash! I apologize if I wasn't clear - I'm struggling to articulate my problem. For example, I'm trying to delete a Task with the mongoDB _id 5c456a1261bc20082ff86977 however, 5c456a1261bc20082ff86974 will be deleted instead (assuming this is the oldest Task _id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, ...)`. If you don't use valid query like `{_id: id}`, it always returns the first object as far as I know.

Mogoose `findOneAndUpdate` accepts `query` as first parameter.More info [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Answer (score 0):

Try to update this.state.id onclick of delete task or pass in e.target.value to delete function and then pick the Id to the api call